# Upgraded Calibre to 5.x, and now I can't right-click "Open with" on Mojave MacOS

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, calibre

I suspect this is a MacOS issue, rather than a Calibre issue. After upgrading from 4.x (which turned out to not be such a bright move), I can no longer right-click on an ebook and select the epub editor via "Open with".

If I do so, the icon appears on the dock briefly, bounces twice, and disappears.

If I've opened it from /Applications, and then loaded the ebook manually with the editor's own file menu, at that point I can go in and open that particular ebook via right-click "Open with". But ebooks that haven't first been opened manually still bounce in the dock and close immediately.

Similarly, I can't drag a file to the docked icon for the editor and expect it to open unless I've first manually opened that file.

This looks suspiciously like some MacOS security feature, but I've not read of that specifically.  But the problem only manifested after the update. Perhaps Calibre 5.x uses some new API which enforces this behavior?

In any event, it has become irritating enough that I need to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Mojave. It turned out that the ebooks I was trying to open in Calibre were quarantined (many were unexpectedly so). Removing the quarantine extended attribute did the trick. In Terminal:

```
xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine path/to/file
```